# Creating Custom Objects at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, object, custom-attributes

I want to create custom objects in C# at runtime, the objects will have properties imported from an xml file. The xml file looks something like this:

```
<field name="FirstName" value="Joe" type="string" />
<field name="DateAdded" value="20090101" type="date" />
```

I would like to create objects in c# that have properties such as FirstName and DateAdded and that have the correct type for the properties. How can I do this? I have tried using a function with if statements to determine the type based on the "type" attribute but I would like to evaluate the types on the fly as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an object? Can't you just use the xml? A dictionary?

Comment: You must tell us the version of C# you are using.

Comment: @Esteban, I need the object because it will allow me to use the types to convert it to different formats for export. 

@Danny, I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx), or more easily using `dynamic` and [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

However, realize that, without knowing the types in advance, it's difficult to use them effectively.  Often, making a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or similar option is an easier choice.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the ExpandoObject.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my C#'s rusty, so Ill tackle this in VB.  Only way I can figure to do it is to use an Object type.  Check out the property type definition and instantiation method below:

```
Private m_myVal As Object
Public Property myVal() As Object
    Get
        Return m_myVal
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        m_myVal = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal valType As String, ByVal val As Object)
    If valType = "string" Then
        myVal = CType(val, String)
    ElseIf valType = "date" Then
        myVal = CType(val, Date)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, for example, create a new instance of the class as:

```
Dim myDynamicClass as New Class1("date","10/21/2010")
```

Your myval property will have a date typed value stored.

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what I have now.